# mms://url streaming in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to do MMS:// streaming on BlackBerry.  I searched a lot but did not get any idea..  can anyone give an idea or a way to do this?

Comment: What have you searched for?  Did you find any close hits?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the JMmsLib.

1. Download the Jar from http://jmmslib.sourceforge.net/index.html
2. Preverify the Jar using the preverify.exe -cldc1.0 flag
3. Add it to your Ant build script and see if RAPC throws any compile errors.

If you're past point three without a lot of hiccups, you *could* be on your way.